# How to create username / password system to .csv file?

Tags: python

Hello I am kinda struggling with this python code. basically I want a way where the user inputs two users, user 1 and user 2, they both have passwords (which i want the password to be hashed / encrypted) But I don't Really know how to do it. 
heres my code so far

```
#Asks for login
gameuniqueid = random.randint(1000,999999)

player1uniqueid = random.randint(1000,9999)
player1 = input("Enter player 1 name: ")
p1p = input("Enter/Create player 1 password: ")
p1_final_score = 0

player2uniqueid = random.randint(1000,9999)
player2 = input("Enter player 2 name: ")
p2p = input("Enter/Create player 2 password: ")
p2_final_score = 0  


print("Your game unique ID is:", gameuniqueid )
#Opens Files and enters information
game = []
user1 = []
user2 = []


file = csv.writer(open("database.csv", "a"))
rows.append(["Game id: ", gameuniqueid])
rows.append([player1uniqueid ,player1, p1p, p1_final_score])
rows.append([player2uniqueid ,player2, p2p, p2_final_score])
file.writerows()
```

So what want is each game in the csv file there will be:

row 1: Unique ID: (Game unique Number)

row 2 : column 1: P1 username  column 2: p1 password column 3: p1_final_score

row 3:  column 1: P2 username  column 2: p2 password 3: p2_final_score

row 4: Nothing

I pretty much want a long list like that every time someone inputs their username and password. then it will be added to the .csv like that I then Want it so that the person can look up their score and details.

I really hope someone can help me with this as I am kinda struggling. if this doesn't really make sense then please let me know.

PS: Full code here: https://codeshare.io/G6oBZN

or if u just want to look https://pastebin.com/hdKFJj6s

Answer (score 0):

Idea of CSV is to store same data format on every line. Like this:

```
gameId,user1Id,user1Name,user1Pass,user1Score,user2Id,user2Name,user2Pass,user2Score
```

So here is the code:

```
import csv
import random
from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context

game_id = random.randint(1000, 999999)
data = [game_id]
for i in range(2):
    data.append(random.randint(1000, 9999))
    data.append(input('Enter player {} name: '.format(i+1)))
    p_pass = input('Enter/Create player {} password: '.format(i+1))
    data.append(pwd_context.hash(p_pass))
    data.append(0)

print('Your game unique ID is: ', game_id)

with open('database.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Output `database.csv`:

```
489042,6139,User1,$6$rounds=656000$YzvCUZobix403Zjm$ApMp4Zo7NzMFcvW3KRYwlcPl9OWHdGONCOQztZwdeUP/fc/6cZFPpIsREGVwvyGk30IqgYrJHq0I5NqBr1KIc.,0,8622,User2,$6$rounds=656000$x50kIsTvVHSBYqfM$/.TCk2qkNxbDRN5r1vyI5gPZ6YWJx5nL1gpUHdkc64trbAqbJHNDfHTJaEaieEE8Pt9IC45Vm4ueytYaMZ13u1,0
```